# unable to provide inputs to the command through c# executing in command window

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, cmd

I am trying to execute a command through c# code on cmd window other than the console window(opens on Ctrl+F5). On executing command it asks for username and password. Now, How should i pass username and password one by one.
And on completion of process it generates 2 lines of output which is to be read inside c# code to be used later on. Updated Code written so far given as:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ios
{
   class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            procStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            procStartInfo.Arguments = "/C java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Normal Sales.viewToken";
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
                process.Start();
                StreamWriter streamWriter = process.StandardInput;
                streamWriter.WriteLine("myusername");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("password");

                streamWriter.Close();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.WaitForExit();
           }
       }

       static void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Output shown : " + outLine.Data);
           if (outLine.Data != null && outLine.Data.Contains("AccessToken"))
           {
                Console.WriteLine("Line Echoed : " + outLine.Data);
           }
           if (outLine.Data != null && outLine.Data.Contains("Expiration Date"))
           {
                Console.WriteLine("Line Echoed : " + outLine.Data);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Now, It is working perfectly with other commands. But the command that i have shown(java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Normal Sales.viewToken) is not taking input as expected. It does not show any output on executing this program. How would i be able to pass inputs and store the output ?

Answer (score 1):

Output strings to your command:

```
cmd.StandartInput.WriteLine("Please Input UserName:");
```

Get strings that users input in Command:

```
string s_UserName = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

And the same for password.

Answer (score 0):

Get your processus base streams :

```
StreamWriter sw = cmd.StandardInput
StreamReader sr = sr.StandardOutput
```

Sending/reading is as easy as sr.ReadLine, sw.Writeline !

Answer (score 0):

Use input/output rederiction

```
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

And the use the `cmd.StandardInput` and `cmd.StandardOutput` to read/write to the process.

Comment: I applied your suggestions in my project and did some more research. I got to know that standard input is working with most of the interactive cmd commands. But my problem still remains i.e. i am not able to provide input automatically to this specific command(java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Normal Sales.viewToken) . I have updated my problem statement.

Comment: @vivekm91 So it for other commands it takes input ? Just for this particular one it does not work ?

Comment: yes.. exactly... for other commands its working fine, it takes input. But for this particular command it does not take input.

Comment: There is a chance since they are asking for user/pass that they intentionally do not allow this approach, but I do  not know for sure, I will try to use this approach with another windows command that asks for user/pass